# Modificar dato que escoja el usuario en matriz

Tags: python

```py
lista_de_productos = [
    ["Linea", "ID", "Descrpcion", "Cantidad", "Precio"],
    [1, 1, "Agua de 1 litro", 100, 15],
    [2, 2, "Leche 1 litro", 100, 25],
    [3, 3, "Manzana", 100, 5],
    [4, 4, "Cereal", 100, 30],
    [5, 5, "Agua de 2 litros", 100, 28],
]

tamaño_lista_de_productos = len(lista_de_productos)
max_tamaño_descripcion = 0
for i in range(tamaño_lista_de_productos):
    if len(lista_de_productos[i][2]) > max_tamaño_descripcion:
        max_tamaño_descripcion = len(lista_de_productos[i][2])
        indice_descripcion = i
for i in range(tamaño_lista_de_productos):
    tamaño_elemento_descripcion = len(lista_de_productos[i][2])
    lista_de_productos[i][2] += " " * (
        len(lista_de_productos[indice_descripcion][2]) - tamaño_elemento_descripcion
    )
max_tamaño_cantidad = 0
for i in range(tamaño_lista_de_productos):
    if len(str(lista_de_productos[i][3])) > max_tamaño_cantidad:
        max_tamaño_cantidad = len(str(lista_de_productos[i][3]))
        indice_cantidad = i
for i in range(tamaño_lista_de_productos):
    tamaño_elemento_cantidad = len(str(lista_de_productos[i][3]))
    lista_de_productos[i][3] = str(lista_de_productos[i][3])
    lista_de_productos[i][3] += " " * (
        len(str(lista_de_productos[indice_cantidad][3])) - tamaño_elemento_cantidad
    )
b = ""
for i in range(tamaño_lista_de_productos):
    for j in range(5):
        b += str(lista_de_productos[i][j]) + "\t"
    print(b)
    b = ""
```

Tengo este código que imprime una matriz sobre una lista de productos, quiero hacer que el usuario pueda modificar la matriz, que seleccione el ID y que pueda cambiar la descripción, cantidad y precio, después volver a mostrar la matriz.

Comment: Este sitio es para resolver dudas, no para hacerte el código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
lista_de_productos = [
    ["Linea", "ID", "Descrpcion", "Cantidad", "Precio"],
    [1, 1, "Agua de 1 litro", 100, 15],
    [2, 2, "Leche 1 litro", 100, 25],
    [3, 3, "Manzana", 100, 5],
    [4, 4, "Cereal", 100, 30],
    [5, 5, "Agua de 2 litros", 100, 28],
]

tamaño_lista_de_productos = len(lista_de_productos)

def modificar_tamaño_descripcion(lista):
    max_tamaño_descripcion = 0
    for i in range(tamaño_lista_de_productos):
        if len(lista[i][2]) > max_tamaño_descripcion:
            max_tamaño_descripcion = len(lista[i][2])
            indice_descripcion = i
    for i in range(tamaño_lista_de_productos):
        tamaño_elemento_descripcion = len(lista[i][2])
        lista[i][2] += " " * (
            len(lista[indice_descripcion][2]) - tamaño_elemento_descripcion
        )
    return lista

def modificar_tamaño_cantidad(lista):
    max_tamaño_cantidad = 0
    for i in range(tamaño_lista_de_productos):
        if len(str(lista[i][3])) > max_tamaño_cantidad:
            max_tamaño_cantidad = len(str(lista[i][3]))
            indice_cantidad = i
    for i in range(tamaño_lista_de_productos):
        tamaño_elemento_cantidad = len(str(lista[i][3]))
        lista[i][3] = str(lista_de_productos[i][3])
        lista[i][3] += " " * (
            len(str(lista[indice_cantidad][3])) - tamaño_elemento_cantidad
        )
    return lista

def lista_por_pantalla(lista):
    b = ""
    for i in range(tamaño_lista_de_productos):
        for j in range(5):
            b += str(lista[i][j]) + "\t"
        print(b)
        b = ""
    return

modificar_tamaño_descripcion(lista_de_productos)
modificar_tamaño_cantidad(lista_de_productos)
lista_por_pantalla(lista_de_productos)

lista_id = []
for i in range(1,tamaño_lista_de_productos):
    lista_id.append(str(lista_de_productos[i][1]))

while True:
    mod_id = input("\nElija el ID que desee modificar: ")

    if mod_id in lista_id:
        fila_a_modificar = lista_id.index(mod_id) + 1
        break
    else:
        print("\nEl ID introducido no se encuentra en la lista de prodcutos.\n")

print("\t".join(lista_de_productos[0]))
for valor_columna in lista_de_productos[fila_a_modificar]:
    print(str(valor_columna), end="\t")

print("\n\nMODIFICACIONES:")
descrip_mod = input("Descripcion: ")
lista_de_productos[fila_a_modificar][2] = descrip_mod
cant_mod = int(input("   Cantidad: "))
lista_de_productos[fila_a_modificar][3] = cant_mod
precio_mod = int(input("     Precio: "))
lista_de_productos[fila_a_modificar][4] = precio_mod

modificar_tamaño_descripcion(lista_de_productos)
modificar_tamaño_cantidad(lista_de_productos)
print("\nNUEVA LISTA:")
lista_por_pantalla(lista_de_productos)
```

Comment: Deberias colocar una explicacion del codigo para mejorar tu respuesta.